# Hungarian umlaut in \documentclass{amsart}?

Tags: amsart

does anybody how to render the Hungarian umlaut in `\documentclass{amsart}`?
I know how to do it in `\documentclass{article}` (it's the command `\H`) but I need it in `\documentclass{amsart}`.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  `amsart` was constructed in such a way that almost anything that works in `article` should also work without change in `amsart`.  The only significant difference is that the top matter (authors and related elements) need to be coded differently.

Comment: `\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
Erd\H{o}s
\end{document}` compiles for me and produces *Erdős* as expected (you may or may not want to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and/or `\usepackage{lmodern}` to the preamble). Did that not work for you? Can you show us a short example document that explains how `\H` did not work for you?

Comment: If you want to write it directly from the keyboard you may need to use the inputenc package with option utf8 kand make sure the doc is saved in utf8 encoding) plus fontenc as moewe mentions. Note that modern larex systems will assume utf8 by default, not true on 8lder systems

Comment: `\H` is defined in latex not in `article` class, why do you think it shouldn't work in `amsart` did you try it and get an error?

Answer (score 1):

The macro `\H` seems also to work in `amsart`.  But if you ever needed a cheap imitation...

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\Humlaut[1]{\stackengine{-.05ex}{#1}{\hstretch{.8}{\vstretch{.65}{%
  \mkern1mu\scriptscriptstyle''}}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{S}}

\H u H\Humlaut{u}ngarian umlaut
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico But I'm not Hongarian.

Comment: Thank you, Steven! Your ``cheap imitation'' worked!!

Comment: @LoredanaLanzani Thank you, and welcome to the site.  If no one else provides a better answer to your question in the coming days, and if this one provides what you need, you might consider clicking the check mark to the left of my answer to "accept" it as the best of the answers provided.  This will also serve to tell other readers what answer  of the several you found worked best for you.